# Does prometheus read the file with token EACH TIME it makes a request?

Tags: prometheus

I am going to integrate alerting functionality of prometheus soon. The app I'm working on changes pool of authorised tokens each hour. I wonder if it is **MY** responsibility to make a post request on `reload` endpoint and trigger reloading of the configuration or maybe prometheus will do it itself? I'm not sure how to make prometheus use the latest token.

*Additional question if prometheus does it itself:*

Does it reload token on 401 http error or maybe each time it makes a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be re-read on each request for bearer tokens.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not right. I wanted to ensure myself, so I've created a test environment in Kubernetes. The conclusion is that you MUST either post a request to ```/reload``` endpoint or call ```kill pid_of_ prometheus -HUP``` to reload prometheus config. It will not reload the token automatically. Additionally, I've tried to return status code 401 whenever prometheus made a request but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Only on older versions, newer versions get this right.

Comment: Right! Since vee 2.2! Thank you